# How to sort Items in ListView

Tags: java, android, sorting, listview

I've got a `ListView`. Each `Item` got 3 `TextViews`. How can I sort `Items` in alphabetical order regarding `TextView` of certain `id`?

My `Adapter` code is as follows:

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

private final Activity context;
private final String[] textName;
private final String[] imagePath;
private final String[] textAge;
private final String[] textSex;
public CustomList(Activity context,
                   String[] imagePath, String[] textName, String[] textSex, String[] textAge) {
    super(context, R.layout.listview_row, textName);
    this.context = context;
    this.textName = textName;
    this.imagePath = imagePath;
    this.textAge = textAge;
    this.textSex = textSex;

}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row_mix, null, false);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.NameText);
    TextView txtSex = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.SexText);
    TextView txtAge = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.AgeText);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    txtTitle.setText(textName[position]);
    txtSex.setText(textSex[position]);
    txtAge.setText(textAge[position]);
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

    File imageFile = new File(root + "/WorkImages/" + imagePath[position]);
    Log.i("Debug", imageFile.toString());
    if(imageFile.exists()){
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
        imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        Log.i("Debug", imageFile.toString());

    }else{
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.profile_icon);}
    return rowView;


 }
}
```

I think sorting should be conducted in the `adapter` code. I looked at similar question, but they worked with with 1 `TextView` `Items`, which meant that they could simply compare and sort values inside `String[]`. If I do similar here, I'll just mess up the list, since names and info won't correspond.

Comment: Arrays.sort(string_arr);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_comparator.htm) as reference.

Instead `Dog(String n, int a)`, I write something to suit my need. In this case `Dog(String a, String b, String c, String d)`. Then I add functions similar to

```
public string getDogName(){
return name;
}
```

like

```
public string getDogSex(){
return sex;
}
```

Then in Activity I use this:

```
list.add(new Dog(a[pos], b[pos], c[pos], d[pos]));
```

where `a, b, c, d` are `String[]`

The sorting itself is made with

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

If you want to change what exactly gets sorted, you change this string.

```
return (this.name).compareTo(d.name);
```

You write multiple possibilities, like `return (this.age).compareTo(d.age);`,
surround them with `if` statement.

```
if(counter == 1){
return (this.name).compareTo(d.name);
}
```

Where counter is `public static int;`. The value gets changed through `button.onClickListener` - it allows for dynamic sorting.

If this looks confusing try working only with code provided in the link, and only after that attempt to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Comparator interface and sort the list then set the data to adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Consider wrapping all the data relevant to a single row (ie. name, image path, sex and age) in a class and then sorting a collection of those objects.

Answer (score 0):

you can use comparator and sort your list data

```
  Collections.sort(array, new Comparator<ListData>() {


           @Override
            public int compare(ListData s1, ListData s2) {
                int returnValue = 0;
                if (!s1.getName().toLowerCase().startsWith(str.toLowerCase())
                        && !s2.getName().toLowerCase().startsWith(str.toLowerCase())
                        || s1.getName().toLowerCase().startsWith(str.toLowerCase())
                        && s2.getName().toLowerCase().startsWith(str.toLowerCase())) {
                    returnValue = s1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(s2.getName());
                } else {
                    if (s1.getName().toLowerCase().startsWith(str.toLowerCase())) {
                        returnValue = -1;
                    } else {
                        returnValue = 1;
                    }
                }
                return returnValue;
            }
        });
```

Comment: should I put this in Adapter or Activity?

Comment: set the adapter again with the new sorted array

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to keep whole dataset in a single data structure, sort them using a `Comparator` instance and hold a copy of that dataset.

First create POJO with name, age, sex, imagePath. This way you don't have to sort each one of your collections individually.

```
public class Person {
    public String imagePath;
    public String name;
    public String age;
    public String sex;
}
```

Second, store these `Person` instances inside a collection. Let's assume we are using java Array, as you did with the adapter example.

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Person[] people;
    // Other stuff...
}
```

Now, let's add the `Comparator` instance and a copy of dataset.

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Person[] people;
    private Comparator<Person> comparator;
    private Person[] peopleSorted;

    // Other stuff...
}
```

So, the final `Adapter` implementation will be similar to

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Person[] people;
    private Comparator<Person> comparator;
    private Person[] peopleSorted;

    public CustomList(Activity context, Person[] people) {
        super(context, R.layout.listview_row, textName);
        this.context = context;
        this.people = people;
        this.peopleSorted = Arrays.copyOf(people, people.length);
    }

    public void sort(Comparator<Person> comparator) {
        if (comparator == null) {
            peopleSorted = Arrays.copyOf(people, people.length);
        }
        else {
            Arrays.sort(peopleSorted, comparator);
        }

        // It is up to you to call notifyDataSetChanged implicitly here, or calling it explicitly from somewhere else. 
    }

    public void getCount() {
        return peopleSorted.length;
    }

    // Other stuff...
}
```

**Notice that**, sort API is allowing you to support Open/Closed principle by taking advantage of polymorphism. How things will get sorted is not Adapter's responsibility anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use direct list as following example

```
List<Type> data_source,order;

Collections.sort(data_source);
//or
Collections.sort(data_source, new Sorter(order));
```

**I hope help this**

Comment: Should I put this in MainActivity?

Answer (score -1):

This sorts the data in ascending order by default.

```
Collections.sort(galaxiesList);
```

We can then reverse it into descending, which is the opposite of ascending:

```
Collections.reverse(galaxiesList)
```